# Internet Explorer 6

Tags: forms, post, header, internet-explorer-6, edit

I'm developing a Web-page into my device based on MCU (ARM-CM3).
Due to I'm very limited in resources (especially in RAM), I was forced to limit an input
buffer for HTTP requests up to 1KiB. I try to support as many versions of browsers as possible, and IE6 - is one of them.
The matter is when I'm using IE6 to upload firmware to the device (via form->submit) the POST header is very large for my device 'cause it contains very unuseful information: such as "Accept" and "User-Agent" headers. Is the way to reduce or change it?
And second question: how to omit the full path of file in 'Content-Disposition' header in POST request?

Comment: Why is this specifically related to IE6? all browsers attach additional headers to each request.

Comment: just because of I came across the problem exactly in IE. In other browsers I tested all works good (FF 5 - FF 23, Opera 9 - 16, lastest Chrome). Maybe ones attach additional information, but not so much. and by the way, due to unknown reason for me IE6 transmits even some adv. informarion in UserAgent field! (this is a link to some web site).  The second specific feature of IE6 - full path instead Fakepath

Comment: For example, if user selects the file located in "My Documents" directory ( or absolutly real situation - somewere in deepest directory in "Desktop") the path will contain for example C:\Documents and settings\LamerName\My documents\firmware.zip.

Comment: Not horrible enough, but ten to one the path will contain also non-latin characters (cyrillics), and 'cause of this fact big part of path will be encoded to hex - 3 bytes per one character! And now I try to find approach to reduce the length of a request body.

Comment: i'm thinking you might be looking for the wrong solution... no way to improve streaming on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. just there no free resources